# why element animation does not work until changing the body's cursor style and refresh the page?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have follow this github "building website" [tutorials](https://github.com/codewithsadee/wren/tree/master),  when set the "hero" part, i add an animation to ".hero .shape" as the author suggested:

```
.hero .shape {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;

  animation: heroDecoAnim 3s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes heroDecoAnim {
  0% { transform: translateY(40px) rotate(0); }
  100% { transform: translateY(0) rotate(0.4turn); }
}
```

Then i got nothing changed on the page(the animation does not work), but after i accidentally deleted my own cursor style of the body back to the author's code and refresh the page, the ".hero .shape" animation came back and executed normally.
My css style for  is:

```
body {
    background-color: var(--bg-oxford-blue-2);
    color: var(--text-shadow-blue);
    font-family: var(--fontFamily-noto_sans);
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: var(--lineHeight-4);
    overflow-y: overlay;
    cursor: wait; /* Here i changed the cursor style to 'wait' type */
}
```

The author's css style code for  is:

```
body {
  background-color: var(--bg-oxford-blue-2);
  color: var(--text-shadow-blue);
  font-family: var(--fontFamily-noto_sans);
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: var(--lineHeight-4);
  overflow-y: overlay;
}
```

Web platform: Chrome Version 112.0.5615.137 (Official Build) (x86_64) (I also test it on the sarifa and got the same results)
Code platform: Brackets.

I accidentally deleted my own cursor style of the body back to the author's code and refresh the page, the ".hero .shape" animation came back and executed normally.

So, i wonder if there are some relationships between the body's cursor setting and my ".hero .shape" element's animation ? I would very appreciate it if anyone can help me figure it out.

Comment: Could you make a runnable snippet. In particular what is the shape (eg an img, a canvas, an svg)? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example